# Android OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener called with wrong preference value for SwitchPreferenceCompat

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm on API level 22 and using a PreferenceFragmentCompat.

I have defined all the preferences in an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="AUDIO0_PREAMP"
        android:title="AUDIO0_PREAMP"/>
...
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Then I want to listen to changes of these preferences:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
...
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        SwitchPreferenceCompat preference = (SwitchPreferenceCompat)findPreference(key);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSharedPreferenceChanged: " + key + ", value: " + (preference.isChecked() ? "1" : "0"));
    }
```

However when I change the preference on the UI, the *onSharedPreferenceChanged* gets called 2 times. First time with the correct value, second time with a 0 value. I'm wondering why this happens and how can I solve it?

Here is a logcat when I change the preference's value to *TRUE*:

```
D/SettingsFragment: onSharedPreferenceChanged: AUDIO0_PREAMP, value: 1
D/SettingsFragment: onSharedPreferenceChanged: AUDIO0_PREAMP, value: 0
```

And here is a logcat when I change it back to *FALSE*:

```
D/SettingsFragment: onSharedPreferenceChanged: AUDIO0_PREAMP, value: 0
D/SettingsFragment: onSharedPreferenceChanged: AUDIO0_PREAMP, value: 0
```

Now of course I can initialize a barrier to only process the first call to this method but it is not elegant and it will only hide the problem.

I want to know the exact cause of this, and the proper way of solving.

UPDATE1:
I change the preference value manually on the UI with my fingers - or on the emulator with the mouse. I have this issue on the real device and on emulator as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Add the code where you are changing the values

Comment: I change it by touching with my fingers - or clicking by mouse on the emulator.

Comment: when I click a preference and it goes to 'checked' state I want to only receive a "value: 1". Or in worst case scenario: more values with wrong data but at the end one with a correct one. Now when I set the preference to checked I got a wrong value at the end. (value: 0).

Comment: Thats why i asked for the code, to look into it, if there is something wrong

Comment: Which code are you referring actually? It is not welcome here to post unrelated code segments as far as I know.

Comment: the code for button's click listener, where shared preference called to save the new value

Comment: There is no code for that!! The class extends PreferenceFragmentCompat. If you read the class documentation it starts with this sentence: "Shows a hierarchy of Preference objects as lists. These preferences will *automatically* save to SharedPreferences as the user interacts with them"

Comment: `However when I change the preference on the UI` this one

Comment: manually means manually. by hand. as an end-user. To be more clear with my own finger I touch the real device's touchscreen then the preference changes. Then the change is handled automatically by the Android SDK - as I've already pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this, and it's working fine. Try with Preference category
Add Gradle dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
```

Then preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="Category 1">

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
                android:key="AUDIO0_PREAMP"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:title="AUDIO0_PREAMP"/>

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
                android:key="key1"
                android:title="Switch Preference"
                android:summary="Switch Summary"
                android:defaultValue="true" />

        <EditTextPreference
                android:key="key2"
                android:title="EditText Preference"
                android:summary="EditText Summary"
                android:dialogMessage="Dialog Message"
                android:defaultValue="Default value" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="key3"
                android:title="CheckBox Preference"
                android:summary="CheckBox Summary"
                android:defaultValue="true"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>



</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Then Fragment

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentPreferences extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences,rootKey);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        SwitchPreferenceCompat preference = (SwitchPreferenceCompat)findPreference(key);
        Log.d("PreferenceChanged", "onSharedPreferenceChanged: " + key + ", value: " + (preference.isChecked() ? "1" : "0"));
    }
}
```

Try Above, if that's not working then post comment

Comment: Explain your changes

Comment: Added preference category @Zun

Comment: Best to explain those changes in your answer. It's not up to us to find your changes

Comment: Still not working. One thing I have noticed: if the default value is false upon start, I get values 1 then 0 after setting it to true. However if default value is true I get values 0 then 1 after setting it to false. Have you tried with API 22 emulator?

Comment: One thing which brings the solution closer is to not use *findPreference* directly. Use the *sharedPreferences* variable in the changelistener, it will give the correct value. However the changelistener still gets called 2 times every time.

Comment: Okay, it was a user error. onCreatePreferences gets called 2 times so it registered 2 times the listener which confused the whole preference system. After fixing that issue now everything works as intended. Thanks very much!